# How to make own OTA app in AOSP - fslota?

Tags: android, android-source, ota

we have build Android from sources and it looks good on our device. Currently we need to make own OTA process, but we dont know how.

We try to implement FSLOTa (https://github.com/embest-tech/android_packages_apps_fsl_imx_demo/tree/master/FSLOta) against our http server, but documentation is very poor - so we simply add source to our source and compile it.

Problem is, that we see app in our box, but it doesnt nothing.

Or there is way to modify built in OTA app, when we change server to our server, we get http request at least. But we dont know, how tells http server to box about new version - any manifest file? XML, JSON or? Is there any example?

Or is there another simple way for implements OTA update to AOSP?

Thank you very much
D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I dont know about FSLOTa nor do I know about the device you are working on. But If you want to implement your own OTA process you could try the following (Just a short draft since your question is very broad):

1. Create a system app that checks from time to time your server for new packages.
2. if it detects a new package it downloads it to your device.
3. it copies the downloaded `update.zip` to `/cache/`
4. Then the app creates the following file `/cache/recovery/command` and writes `--update_package=path_to_your_file` in it. (For more commands see /bootable/recovery.cpp)
5. Then it forces a reboot into `recovery`
6. recovery installs your ota package.

---

Update:
I quickly checked the app you linked. I would check these things:

1. Do you get till the point where `RecoverySystem.installPackage()` is called ? (https://github.com/embest-tech/android_packages_apps_fsl_imx_demo/blob/master/FSLOta/src/com/fsl/android/ota/OTAServerManager.java#L282)
2. Do you see a message in logcat from the `RecoverySystem` that it is going to reboot? (maybe you have a permission problem and your app is not allowed to force "reboot recovery")
3. Is the path to your update.zip correct? (it should be in /cache/)

Comment: Hello, thank you very much. Actually we trying your advices and I will write result to you. Thanks!!!!!!

Comment: Hi @DariusRadius, Would you like to share how can I update my own apk which is not installed through google play? and I have the system level access. Thanks.

Comment: @skygeek the steps are pretty much the same as in this answer

Comment: @IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII okay, actually I am pretty new on this OTA thing so don't have much understanding about the zip structure and parameters to put for new or updated app. I will explore. BTW, thanks for quick reply.

Answer (score 1):

I think the [Lineage OS Updater package](https://github.com/LineageOS/android_packages_apps_Updater) is a good answer to your question. LineageOS is a branch of AOSP and is committed to fully open source development of all parts of the Android OS. As part of this commitment, the community has developed a full over-the-air update cycle including a client application and a few server side projects.

In my recent experience, I could fully embed the LineageOS updater with the AOSP project and certainly, it works! There are a few steps toward fully embedding. I tried to describe it via the following question. [How to use Lineage OS OTA in AOSP projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73267251/how-to-use-lineage-os-ota-in-aosp-projects)

The project works for both full and incremental updates, but only adapted to A/B devices. I do not think you can easily use it in non-A/B devices.

Answer (score 0):

i have been developing an OTA updater android application, you should know application send request to backend server and receive a JSON file about the available update. everything [iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5183341/iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii) anwserd was ok on non/AB devices, but for A/B devices, the android application downloads the OTA package under /data
and installation will not happen in recovery or anything, the changes will apply to the unused slot before REBOOT.