# Build AOSP 7 with restricted App installing access

Tags: android, embedded-linux, android-source, rom

I want to build AOSP for a device and sell it to someone. But I want the ROM to not allow installing any apps (except some my own apps) via sideloading or another way. How can I restrict app installing access? Do I have to write a setting app and keep (untrusted sourses) unchecked?

Answer (score 0):

Very broad topic but I try to give you an overview of a possible solution. First I assume that the AOSP version you want to sell has no Play store and has adb disabled for its end users.

First, you include the certificates you used to sign your apps in your AOSP version.

Then you need to provide some kind of your own Play store app so your users can download your apps to the device. The app checks the certificates and if everything is ok it forces the device to boot into recovery where the apps certificates get checked again / the app gets installed (For more info about this step check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43232518/5183341)).